# Angular character encoding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding

I'm trying to display values returned from a database that can be html encoded

`what&#39;s up!`

Inside of an ng-repeat, I'm outputting this values and passing the value to a function for processing and having that return using the 'trustAsHtml' function.

`return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);`

When I first load the page, everything looks great. The value gets outputted as `what's up!` however, if I add values to the model, they will get outputted as the encoded version, until I reload the page.

Any ideas on this? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngBindHtmlUnsafe

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat=" opt in opts" ng-bind-html-unsafe="getContent(opt)" >
        {{ opt.value }}
    </li>
    </ul>

    <p>{{opt}}</p>
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.getContent = function(obj){
        return obj.value + " " + obj.text
    }
    $scope.opts = [
        {value: 111, text: '<b>1st</b>' },
        {value: 222, text: '<i>2nd</i>' }
    ];
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFFBa/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but I found this can help you.You can create a directive by which you use the $watch function for update $sce.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <b>User comments</b><br>
  <div class="well">
    <div ng-repeat="userComment in myCtrl.userComments">
      <span ng-bind-html="userComment.htmlData"></span>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

var ngBindHtmlDirective = ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch($sce.parseAsHtml(attr.ngBindHtml), function(value) {
      element.html(value || '');
    });
  };
}];
```